# SQL Code running perfectly in oracle 11g not running after upgrading to 19c

Tags: sql, oracle

In 11g, this code is running and returning a value.
But after upgrading to 19c, this code returns an error ORA-01843: not a valid month.

note: if we comment rn=1 (where condition in out block), then the query is running

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Well this `19-DEC-21` is not a stable was of defining date literals as you depend on `NLS` setting that was probably changed in the upgrade - use `DATE-2021-12-19`.

Answer (score 3):

Don't compare dates to strings. Should be

```sql
and trunc(e.created_date) = date '2021-12-19'
                            -----------------
                            -- This is DATE datatype
```

because - what you used, is wrong

```sql
and trunc(e.created_date) = ('19-DEC-21')
                            -------------
                            -- This is a STRING
```

Why is it wrong? Because it depends on NLS settings. Apparently, those two databases differ in them. You were "lucky" in 11g as Oracle managed to implicitly convert that string to a valid DATE datatype value.

Comment: `e.created_date >= date '2021-12-19' and e.created_date < date '2021-12-19' + 1` to eliminate partitioning and idexes